# C++ implementation of recursive_shared_mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, locking

I know it's bad to even use recursive_mutex because of its poor performance, let alone a recursive shared mutex. However, I'm doing this just to practice. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

> recursive_shared_mutex.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <optional>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>

class recursive_shared_mutex : private std::shared_mutex {
public:
    recursive_shared_mutex();
    ~recursive_shared_mutex() = default;
    
    void lock();
    bool try_lock();
    void unlock();

    /*
    * std::shared_mutex's shared locking is recursive by default.
    */
    void lock_shared() {
        std::shared_mutex::lock_shared();
    }

    bool try_lock_shared() {
        return std::shared_mutex::try_lock_shared();
    }
    
    void unlock_shared() {
        std::shared_mutex::unlock_shared();
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::optional<std::thread::id> writer_id_;
    std::size_t writer_cnt_;
};
```

> recursive_shared_mutex.cpp

```
#include "recursive_shared_mutex.hpp"

recursive_shared_mutex::recursive_shared_mutex()
    : std::shared_mutex(),
      mtx_(),
      cv_(),
      writer_id_(),
      writer_cnt_(0)
{
}

void recursive_shared_mutex::lock() {
    std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(mtx_);
    if (this_id == writer_id_) {
        // Same thread/writer trying to acquire the shared_mutex again.
        // Simply increase writer count.
        ++writer_cnt_;
    }
    else {
        // Another writer or no writer is holding the shared_mutex.
        // It's also likely that some readers are holding
        // the shared_mutex.
        if (writer_id_.has_value()) {
            // If another writer is holding the mutex,
            // waiting for it to release.
            cv_.wait(ulock, [this] { return writer_cnt_ == 0; });
        }
        std::shared_mutex::lock();
        writer_id_ = this_id;
        writer_cnt_ = 1;
    }
}

bool recursive_shared_mutex::try_lock() {
    // TODO
    return false;
}

void recursive_shared_mutex::unlock() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(mtx_);
    if (!writer_id_.has_value()) {
        // No writer is holding the shared_mutex.
        // Call unlock() anyway. UB expected.
        std::shared_mutex::unlock();
    }
    else {
        // At this point, the shared_mutex must be held by a writer
        // and writer_cnt_ must be greater than 0.
        --writer_cnt_;
        if (writer_cnt_ == 0) {
            // If writer count becomes 0, release the
            // underlying shared_mutex.
            // It's likely that we are unlocking in a
            // different thread from the one where the shared_mutex
            // has been acquired.
            // Call unlock() anyway. UB expected.
            std::shared_mutex::unlock();
            writer_id_.reset();
            // Manually unlock to let cv notify.
            ulock.unlock();
            cv_.notify_one();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_mutex's shared locking is recursive by default` - this is not true. What you are seeing is a side effect of running on a system which implement `shared_mutex` using `pthread_rwlock_t` which allows taking read lock multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend *not* inheriting from standard types, and *not* using private inheritance even with your own types. If a `recursive_shared_mutex` IS-A `shared_mutex`, then announce it publicly; if it IS-NOT-A `shared_mutex`, then don't use inheritance at all!

([Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/nr3dax) `D_view` here is isomorphic to `std::reference_wrapper<D>`, for what that's worth.)

---

```
std::size_t writer_cnt_;
```

should be

```
std::size_t writer_cnt_ = 0;
```

so that you don't have to remember to initialize it in the member-initializer-list of the constructor. Once you do that, you can `=default` your constructor. Even if you don't `=default` the constructor, please don't do `mtx_(), cv_(),` and so on. Let default constructors do their jobs; and don't force me to read more code than I need to read.

---

```
    // No writer is holding the shared_mutex.
    // Call unlock() anyway. UB expected.
```

This comment is just completely bogus. If this situation is "should never happen, UB expected," then **assert false already!** Don't just go on and do some random operation like `shared_mutex::unlock()` when you **know** you're in a bad state. Assert false, and let the programmer detect and fix their bug.

Again, this follows the mantra "Don't force me to read more code than I have to." Don't make me read a codepath that does `shared_mutex::unlock()` and returns, when really that codepath is unreachable. In fact, don't even write that `if` test! Just do this:

```
void recursive_shared_mutex::unlock() {
    auto lk = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx_);
    assert(writer_id_.has_value());
    assert(*writer_id_ == std::this_thread::id());
    assert(writer_cnt_ > 0);
    if (--writer_cnt_ == 0) {
        std::shared_mutex::unlock();  // oops, TODO FIXME
        writer_id_ = std::nullopt;
        lk.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Notice my preferred use of `lk` for lock-guard variables.
Notice I'm avoiding the use of ad-hoc named methods like `x.reset()` in favor of value-semantic operations like `x = nullopt`.

You've still got a bug here, which you code-commented — but commenting a bug doesn't make it go away! Frankly, this code is *literally* off-topic here, because it doesn't work and you know it doesn't work.

Figure out how to use a semaphore (from the `<semaphore>` header in C++20) or an `atomic`, instead of the `shared_mutex` which you already know gives you UB.

---

I'm 90% sure that there's a deadlock possible between your exclusive `lock()` and `unlock()` functions. Suppose Thread A has the mutex exclusive-locked, and Thread B goes to lock it. Then Thread B will enter `lock()`, take an exclusive lock on `mtx_`, and block in `std::shared_mutex::lock()` because Thread B still has it locked. (Assume Thread B drops its lock just long enough to fool the `cv_.wait()` loop.) Finally, Thread A enters `unlock()` and blocks in `ulock(mtx_)` because Thread B still has `mtx_` locked.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed post. I do agree with you on the constructor thing. It makes code more concise if I declare a default ctor. However, I have different opinions on other "issues" you've pointed out. I know private inheritance can be problematic but should we really avoid using it under any circumstance? As far as I know, private inheritance means Implemented-In-Terms-Of. In this case, pointer/reference of recursive_shared_mutex can't be converted to pointer/reference of std::shared_mutex, so it's safe to use private inheritance here imo.

Comment: As for the UB thing, because my `recursive_shared_mutex` is implemented in terms of `std::shared_mutex`, and in c++ standard, doing such things with `std::shared_mutex` leads to UB, I think it makes more sense to call `std::shared_mutex::unlock()` anyway than fail an assertion.

Comment: As for `cv` and its `wait()` method, the thread that calls `wait()` will sleep and `unique_lock` will be unlocked if the lambda is evaluated to be false. So there won't be deadlock. See the below code snippet.

Comment: `class Mtx : public mutex {
public:
    void lock() {
        mutex::lock();
        cout << "locked\n";
    }

    void unlock() {
        mutex::unlock();
        cout << "unlocked\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Mtx mtx;
    condition_variable_any cv;
    unique_lock<Mtx> lk(mtx);
    cv.wait(lk, [] { return false; });
    cout << "after wait\n";

    return 0;
}`

Comment: output is `locked
unlocked`

Comment: @Einiemand: Re private inheritance, take a look at the Godbolt I posted. Also see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance and perhaps https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types/  Re the deadlock, I'm still pretty confident it's there. Try to prove to yourself that it _is_ there.

Comment: I can't think of an occasion where there would be a deadlock. If code reaches `std::shared_mutex::lock()`, it is guaranteed that the mutex is not held by any other writer.